# ASUS X-99 Deluxe Wireless Antenna Installation

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard

I have a relatively new workstation with an ASUS X-99 Deluxe motherboard.  This model features a built-in wireless adapter, and comes with a wireless antenna.  When I connect the antenna to the ports in the back, however, I am not able to see any wireless networks.

The physical connection itself is a little unusual, but it seems to set and stay connected with a small twist.  Has anyone installed the antenna on this model?  Any thoughts on why it's not working? My assumption is that since it's a built-in, it's not a driver problem.

**EDIT**:  I foolishly did not mention that I am working with Ubuntu 14.10 as my OS.  I should also mention that I am able to connect to the internet via a hardline connection from a network range extender (so a hardline connection to a wireless access point).  I need to move the extender to increase performance, which is why this has come up.  I will need to use the wireless antenna exclusively.

Comment: You have verified the device is report as being functional in Device Manager?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified.  The device does not appear to be recognized if my interpretation is correct.  `lshw` indicates that the wireless adapter exists, but it is `UNCLAIMED`.  The antenna has been connected in a manner consistent with the single image in the manual.

Comment: What operating system are we dealing with.  I only assumed it was Windows but your response makes me question that assumption.